# Why is ngxClipboard complaining about needing an input element?

Tags: angular, input, ngx-clipboard

I have a fairly basic reactive form in Angular 5 with the following [ngx-clipboard](https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-clipboard) markup:

```
<form [formGroup]="shareForm">
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="shareUrl" 
          placeholder="Click to copy URL" readonly="true" 
          [ngxClipboard]="currentUrl" (cbOnSuccess)="onClipboardCopy()">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

However, the page throws an error:

> Error: Target should be input or textarea

Why does ngx-clipboard not see the input as the target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://github.com/maxisam/ngx-clipboard#usage) imply the use of one directive or the other. I got it working by using both directives.

```
<input matInput formControlName="shareUrl"
  placeholder="Click to copy URL"
  readonly="true"
  ngxClipboard [cbContent]="currentUrl" (cbOnSuccess)="onClipboardCopy()">
       ^--- here    ^--- and here
```